# Problem with QFieldSync "offline editing" for more than one layer

Tags: qgis, qfield, geopackage

I want to edit two layers with QField offline ("offline editing"): A polygon- and a line geometry (both stored as sep. layers in a gpkg, no multigeometries). While packing it with QFieldSync, an error appears, which says: `WARNING FEHLER: Layer ist nicht veränderbar` (s. like: Error: Layer is not editable/changeable). Well, both layers were exported to QField, but one layer is empty (missing all the geometries), the other one is ok. I assume, there is some sort of conflict, but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it. This problem has to do with the storage system, namely exporting the files via QField Sync to a folder on a QNAP (NAS). Probably the conflicts arise because of the Linux storage system on QNAP.  By exporting to a Windows file system, the problems disappear.